# Creating a model through the admin panel inside the test

Tags: python, django, testing, admin

I'm new to Python. I'm trying to create a test that will create an item inside the admin panel, but when I run the test I get: AssertionError: False is not true.
Help me please

```
class ItemAdminTest(TestCase):
    serialized_rollback = True

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.user = User.objects.create_superuser(email='admin@example.com', password='admin')

    def test_create_item_admin(self):
        self.client.login(email='admin@example.com', password='admin')

        response = self.client.post('/admin/product/item/add/', {
            'title': 'Test Item',
            'description': 'Test Description',
            'price': 10.00,
            'code': 123456,
            'color': 'Red',
            'weight': 1.5,
            'height': 10.0,
            'width': 5.5,
            'types': ["КБТ", "МБТ"],
            'amount': 5,
        })

        self.assertTrue(Item.objects.filter(title='Test Item').exists())
```

At the same time, I am absolutely sure that a superuser is created and authorization is successful, but for some reason the item itself is not created.

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `TestCase`, `Client`, `User` and `Item` are not defined.  what are all of these ?

Comment: User and Item - models in project
TestCase and Client - import from django.test